# 'The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing' error

Tags: docker, testing, dockerfile, cypress, docker-image

I have a problem with configuration of dockerfile. I want to docker image with cypress. Here is my code in dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/included:10.11.0
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN npm install --save-dev mochawesome
RUN npm install --save-dev mochawesome-merge
```

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  npm_config_cache: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm"
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress"

stages:
  - test
  - report

test:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxx/gitlab-ci/cypress-ci
  stage: test
  script:
    - npx cypress run --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=reports/all-tests.xml,toConsole=true"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - reports/all-tests.xml
  allow_failure: true
```

In the gitlab pipeline I'm getting error

> > The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing. We expected the binary to be installed here:
> > /builds/veloxalpha/tests/front-tests/cache/Cypress/10.11.0/Cypress/Cypress
> > Reasons it may be missing:
>
> - You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /root/.cache/Cypress
> - You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: /root/.cache/Cypress Properly caching the binary will fix this error
>   and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress. Alternatively, you can
>   run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.
>   https://on.cypress.io/not-installed-ci-error

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? :( Thanks for any tips ! :)

Comment: One thing you can do is run `npx cypress install && npm run cypress` in your Docker container. However this will cause Cypress to need to reinstall every time you run the tests, which always takes a few minutes. Have you come up with a better solution by now?